# Loading a html page in lightbox or pop box instated of a new page

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I am developing an admin panel. I have some customer details in a table. When I click on the ID of a customer a new page opens. I want instated of new page, a **pop up box** or **light box** to open, displaying the customer details table, and when I would be able to close it by clicking a close button.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far for code?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i am having an project in code igniter. till now i have tried so many things but all i found is a pop box or light box that can load images only. i need to load  a proper code igniter page